# Transactions behaviour when request times out. [google app engine]

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google app engine has this useful little function in its db class,

```
db.run_in_transaction()
```

Which is suppose to garentee that your method will be rolled back if an exception is raised. "*[If the function raises an exception, the transaction is rolled back.](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#run_in_transaction)*"

What happens if my request times out in the middle of its execution? Will it roll back?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the timeout raises an exception, so that also will mean a rollback.